# I want to create a basic HTML5 Website with RSVP form

Tags: django, html, web

I want to create a basic wedding website for a close friend of mine who is getting married soon.

Something responsive with an RSVP form. I intended to do it with Django as I have some experience with that, but I feel it's an overkill.

Can anyone recommend something very basic/responsive and allows me to store RSVP data easily?

Thanks!

Comment: i think you can go with django but  i think its a bit overkill and suggest you flask and i think i found a flask project that you may use  https://github.com/edwinavalos/flask-rsvp

Comment: I would do the thing in Wordpress with a Plugin. I mean if it is just for one wedding. Doing this with Django or whatever would be total overkill. I mean besides all the coding, you would need to configure a server and everything. Why would you do that to yourself if it is just for one event...